# Props.store does not work on child components

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

please help.

**this.props.store** does not work on child components.

but the connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) ... is working fine.

why doesn't work only child components?

**1. parent code (is working fine)**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Home } from './container/home/index';
import { ChildrenComponent } from './container/childrenComponent';
import { Match, Miss } from 'react-router';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router';

import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import Reducers from './reducers';

const store = createStore(Reducers);
store.subscribe(() => console.log('ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ store was updated ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ'));
store.subscribe(() => console.log(store.getState()));
store.subscribe(() => console.log('ㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡㅡ'));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Match pattern="/" component={Home} />
        <Match pattern="/ChildrenComponent" component={ChildrenComponent} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**2. Children Component (is not working only 'this.props.store ..... ')**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class ChildrenComponent extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
  }
  render (
    console.log(this.props.store) // undfined
    console.log(this.props.store.getState()) // does not working

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        // .... is working fine
      }
    }
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
       // .... is working fine
      }
    }
  )
  return (
    <divHellow world</div>
  )
}

expoert default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildrenComponent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Trying to access the store and its state directly defeats the entire purpose of using Redux, and React-Redux in particular. You're supposed to use `mapStateToProps` to access parts of `state` that you need in each particular component.

Answer (score 0):

Put mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps outside the component class and put your jsx inside the render method of your component class.

```
class ChildrenComponent extends Component {
   render () {
     return (
      <divHellow world</div>
     )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    // ....
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
   // .... 
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ChildrenComponent);
```